# How to use different gateways for different IP addresses when connected to multiple gateways - Win7

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, routing

My office has a LAN and a Open ADSL (without proxy) via WIFI. Though I'm connected to both I can't use them same time. So How am I edit and add routes so for specific ips uses different gateways. I found this article which I don't understand it well.

[Configuring multiple gateways on a network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuring-multiple-network-gateways#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Say your LAN has gateway 192.168.0.1(i.e. IP are in the range 192.168.0.xxx) and WIFI has gateway 192.168.1.1(i.e. IP are in the range 192.168.1.xxx)

use this at **command prompt**:

```
route -p add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 metric 1 if 20
route -p add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 metric 2 if 21
```

Interface index(20,21) says, which interface to use for each route.
Interface index is seen at *route print*[image]

After adding use

```
route print
```

and check if the routes have been added.

Comment: I added routes. But still it's not working. pls correct me if i am wrong.

[Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/6piTlOr.png)

Comment: @PrashanFernando the routes have added. could you detail on the IP ranges of each network, and gateway of each?